# Change the color of a switch

Tags: nativescript

I want to change the color of a toggled on switch on Android. I noticed that the switch has the color of the ns_accent and this color can't be changed because of other elements in my app.

Style.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    ...
    <color name="ns_accent">#00CCBB</color>
</resources>
```

In iOS i already solved the issue with this code:

```
switch.ios.tintColor = UIColor.colorWithRedGreenBlueAlpha(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.5);
switch.ios.onTintColor = UIColor.colorWithRedGreenBlueAlpha(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.5);
```

Also i noticed that i could parse an Android color with this code:

```
android.graphics.Color.parseColor("#B3FFFFFF");
```

---

**Question:** How can i change the switch-on color in Android?

Comment: You can set CSS properties  background-color and color for switch element but still that wil have different results depending on the Android API level

Comment: This solved the issue, thank you!

Comment: Is there availability for checked state css ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it programmatically like this:

```
var Color = colorModule.Color
var switchColor = new Color("#somecolor");

switch.android.getThumbDrawable().setColorFilter(switchColor.android, android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);    
switch.android.getTrackDrawable().setColorFilter(switchColor.android, android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

And yeah, you can replace `switchColor.android` by the code you have found `android.graphics.Color.parseColor("#B3FFFFFF");`

Comment: can you explain how you achieved that?